# Setting fields of different entities in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I have two instances of the same entity class and I am setting a field of the cloned instance. The problem is that when I set the field of the cloned object it seems the original object is being modified too. Is this normal??

```
Corretora clone = original.clone();
clone.setNome(nome);
```

The clone() method:

```
@Override
public Corretora clone()  {
    Corretora c = new Corretora();
    c.setCodigo(codigo);
    c.setDescricao(descricao);
    c.setId(id);
    c.setNome(nome);
    return c;
}
```

where codigo is String, descricao is String, id is Long, nome is String.

Comment: yes cause your `clone()` method makes a shallow copy

Comment: hm... not sure if that is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You really shouldn't be `clone`ing JPA entities; that's likely to confuse the persistence provider to no end, and it may not do what you want. For example, if you're using proxy objects for your entities, you'll be `clone`ing the proxy, and both will still point to the original entity behind them. Even if you grab the object you want (say, you're using AspectJ), the two clones will still have the same ID.

Instead, you should think about why you're trying to use `clone` and find an alternate, less-flaky method of expressing it.